# Hibernate not fetching non-owning entity

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, model-view-controller

I have two tables `category` and `financial_year`. Every `category` has an foreign key pointing to a `financial_year`.

In Spring MVC/ JPA/ Hibernate I have the corresponding entity classes and repository interfaces  (extending `CrudRepository`). When I `findAll` from `CategoryRepository` everything works fine. The `FinancialYear` entity for every `Category` is fetched fine and I am able to display the same through a jsp.

When I try to `findAll` from `FinancialYearRepository` not only are the respective `Category` entities not fetched, even the `FinancialYear` columns are not fetched. The jsp only shows one empty row in the table. Following are the entity classes

```
**Category.java**

package com.ssg...model;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "financial_year_id")
    private FinancialYear financialYear;
    private String name;
    private String description;

...
...
```

```
**FinancialYear.java**

package com.ssg...model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name = "financial_year")
public class FinancialYear implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "financial_year_start")
    private Date financialYearStart;
    @Column(name = "financial_year_end")
    private Date financialYearEnd;
    private String comments;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "financialYear")
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();

...
...
```

```
**JPAConfig.java**

package com.ssg...config;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.ssg...repository" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("pbaPersistenceUnit");
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.ssg...model" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return factoryBean;
    }

...
...
```

When I check the source of the rendered jsp (`financialYears.jsp`) I see the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Shri Ganeshaaya Namaha !!!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <thead>
            <td>FY Start</td>
            <td>FY End</td>
            <td>FY Comments</td>
        </thead>
        <c:forEach items="[com.ssg...model.FinancialYear@41e4e4a5, com.ssg...model.FinancialYear@66363545]" var="fy">

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that someone had down voted my question and rightly so. The person said that there was not enough research effort put in and I agree. The person also said that the question was not clear. However, let me say that I an new to stackoverflow. Some sort of indication as to what direction I need to further investigate and what do I need to add to the question to make it more clear would have helped. A quick terse comment as mentioned above leaves a newbie like me high and dry with nowhere to look for help. So, while I know everyone is super busy, I will request any responders (to any question in the future from anyone) to be more considerate, especially to newcomers so that we can take advantage of this wonderful site.

Having said that, though the comment disappointed me a little bit, it prodded me to spend a little more time on the issue I had, though I am working on a tight schedule and programming is not my main job, and I could resolve the issue. The issue was very very simply that I had not included the jstl taglib in my jsp. A quick view of my code would have revealed it to all you experts out there and it could have been considerate of you to point it out to me.

I accept my mistake and apologize for the same. I would also request all people who are so helpful on this site to also show some consideration to newbies like.

My issue has been resolved.